# What is the difference between these two codes interms of verilog blocking and non blocking assignments?

Tags: verilog

Block1:

```
begin : block1
  X<= #50 10;
  X<= #150 100;
  #50 
  X<= #200 200;
  #500
  X<=#250 250;
end
```

Block 2:

```
begin : block2
  X= #50 10;
  X= #150 100;
  #50
  X= #200 200;
  #500
  X=#250 250;
end
```

I want to know the difference in terms of time delay the X is assigned values, can anybody help me out????

Comment: You should be able to simulate and see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I can help you figure it out without doing your work for you.

A **blocking** assignment means the next statement is *blocked* until the assignment to the variable completes. A **non-blocking** assignment means the assignment to the variable is schedule in the future, but next statement executes *without being blocked*.

Assuming `block1` and `block2` are `begin/end` blocks that both start at time 0, block1 would reach its `end` at time 550 and block2 would reach its `end` at time 1200.

Comment: In the blocking case shouldn't the delay be 1200 further   in the same case does the statement x= #200 200 will be executed after delay of 50 ‚ I mean not concurrently even for delays other than intra operator ones?

Comment: @dave_59 50+150+50+200+500+250=1200

Comment: I mean to say if we have code like  begin : block2
  X= #50 10;
  X= #150 100;
  #50
  B= #200 200;
  #500
  X=#250 250;
end then the statement B= #200 200 will be executed after delay of  250 and the same code for non blocking will assign B after delay of 50 am I correct???