# When I simulate for non blocking assignement in verilog, simulation time is not advancing?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

```
module blocking( );
reg a,c,d,e,f ;
reg b = 'b0;
always 
begin 
a <= #10 b ;
c <= #10 a; 
end 

always
begin
#100;
$stop;
end
always
#10 b = ~b;

endmodule
```

Comment: if keep always @(*) then only it simulates, 
If I use blocking statements , then also it simulates but for the above code, time is not advancing.

Comment: thanks, but I am looking for the reason why it is not working without @(*)?

Comment: Writing only code without necessary description is not recommended in SO. Please carefully read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The first `always` block has no delays in its process. All always blocks insatiate loping procedural threads. Use `always_comb` and it will wait for a change on `b` or `c` to being its loop.

Comment: what about #10. WHen I keep (blocking) = instead of <=(non blocking) it runs. what is the logic behind this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40224011/what-is-the-difference-between-these-two-codes-interms-of-verilog-blocking-and-n/40229430#40229430